# C60 Fullerene Polymers?

Tags: polymers, materials, carbon-allotropes, magnetism

Upon scouring Wikipedia for info about fullerenes to research, I came across this paragraph in the page on [Buckminsterfullerene (C60)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Buckminsterfullerene&oldid=945110359#Cycloadditions):

> Under high pressure and temperature, repeated [2+2] cycloaddition between 
>     C60 results in a polymerized fullerene chains and networks. These polymers 
>     remain stable at ambient pressure and temperature once formed, and have 
>     remarkably interesting electronic and magnetic properties, such as being 
>     [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) above room 
>     temperature.[<sup>[43]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Buckminsterfullerene&oldid=945110359#cite_note-InorgChem-43)

This sounded like a very intriguing topic, and I instantly got hooked. However, the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Buckminsterfullerene&oldid=945110359#cite_note-InorgChem-43) that it cited was "Chapter 14: The group 14 elements" from some inorganic chemistry textbook, and contained little more information than the quote above. Upon performing an internet search, I found little related research, and no online journal that both published the research *and* was one that I had access to. If anyone has more information about this mysterious polymer or it's variations, properties, or related research, I would be grateful.

Note that I'm *not* referring to the dumbbell-shaped *dimer* of C60, which I found plenty of research on. However, all answers and contributions about the polymeric form are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting reaction! Here is what I found: [Dimerization and Fusion of Two C60 Molecules](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0704/0704.2502.pdf) by Kaur et al.